# Pandas Dataframe split multiple key values to different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column with the following format:

```
col1    col2   
 A     [{'Id':42,'prices':['30',’78’]},{'Id': 44,'prices':['20','47',‘89’]}]
 B     [{'Id':47,'prices':['30',’78’]},{'Id':94,'prices':['20']},{'Id':84,'prices':['20','98']}]
```

How can I transform it to the following ?

```
col1    Id            price   
  A     42         ['30',’78’]
  A     44         ['20','47',‘89’]
  B     47         ['30',’78’]
  B     94         ['20']
  B     84         ['20','98']
```

I was thinking of using apply and lambda as a solution but I am not sure how.

Edit : In order to recreate this dataframe I use the following code :

```
data = [['A', "[{'Id':42,'prices':['30','78']},{'Id': 44,'prices':['20','47','89']}]"], 
        ['B', "[{'Id':47,'prices':['30','78']},{'Id':94,'prices':['20']},{'Id':84,'prices':['20','98']}]"]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: kindly output ur data with to_dict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution if there are lists in column `col2`:

```
print (type(df['col2'].iat[0]))
<class 'list'>

L = [{**{'col1': a}, **x} for a, b in df[['col1','col2']].to_numpy() for x in b]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
  col1  Id        prices
0    A  42      [30, 78]
1    A  44  [20, 47, 89]
2    B  47      [30, 78]
3    B  94          [20]
4    B  84      [20, 98]
```

If there are strings:

```
print (type(df['col2'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>

import ast

L = [{**{'col1': a}, **x} for a, b in df[['col1','col2']].to_numpy() for x in ast.literal_eval(b)]
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
  col1  Id        prices
0    A  42      [30, 78]
1    A  44  [20, 47, 89]
2    B  47      [30, 78]
3    B  94          [20]
4    B  84      [20, 98]
```

For better understanding is possible use:

```
import ast

L = []
for a, b in df[['col1','col2']].to_numpy():
    for x in ast.literal_eval(b):
        d = {'col1': a}
        out = {**d, **x}
        L.append(out)

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
  col1  Id        prices
0    A  42      [30, 78]
1    A  44  [20, 47, 89]
2    B  47      [30, 78]
3    B  94          [20]
4    B  84      [20, 98]
```

Comment: What do the ** mean ?

Comment: @colla - It is for merge 2 dictionaries - `z = {**x, **y}`, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python)

Comment: Your answers says I have a syntax error in the following : [{'Id':47,'prices':['30','78'']},{'Id':94,'prices':['20']},{'Id':84,'prices':['20','98']}]  Any ideas why it's doing so ?

Comment: @colla - There is problem in data, it seems some data are messy. Is possible share input data, best json if possible?

Comment: I edited my question so you can recreate my data easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214662/discussion-between-colla-and-jezrael).

Comment: What if the data has date time in col 2?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729933/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-values-from-data-frame-column-to-new-columns-using

Answer (score 2):

Considering second parameter of "data" as list.

```
data= [
  ['A', [{'Id':42,'prices':['30','78']},{'Id': 44,'prices':['20','47','89']}]], 
  ['B', [{'Id':47,'prices':['30','78']}, {'Id':94,'prices':['20']},{'Id':84,'prices': 
        ['20','98']}]]
  ]

t_list = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i][1])):
        t_list.append((data[i][0], data[i][1][j]['Id'], data[i][1][j]['prices']))

df = pd.DataFrame(t_list, columns=['col1', 'id', 'price'])
print(df)

     col1  id         price
0    A     42      [30, 78]
1    A     44  [20, 47, 89]
2    B     47      [30, 78]
3    B     94          [20]
4    B     84      [20, 98]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`df.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) here with [**`pd.Series.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [**`df.set_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [**`df.reset_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df.set_index('col1').explode('col2')['col2'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index()

  col1  Id        prices
0    A  42      [30, 78]
1    A  44  [20, 47, 89]
2    B  47      [30, 78]
3    B  94          [20]
4    B  84      [20, 98]
```

When **`col2`** is string, use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

data = [['A', "[{'Id':42,'prices':['30','78']},{'Id': 44,'prices':['20','47','89']}]"], 
        ['B', "[{'Id':47,'prices':['30','78']},{'Id':94,'prices':['20']},{'Id':84,'prices':['20','98']}]"]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(ast.literal_eval)

df.set_index('col1').explode('col2')['col2'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index()

  col1  Id        prices
0    A  42      [30, 78]
1    A  44  [20, 47, 89]
2    B  47      [30, 78]
3    B  94          [20]
4    B  84      [20, 98]
```